# why does apache forbid access via symbolic links?

Tags: apache2, typo3, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to install typo3 as per the instructions but I have a bit of a puzzle to solve.
It seems apache denies access to any files I try to access via any symbolic link in the site root directory. I have changed permissions from **SymLinksIfOwnerMatch** to **FollowSymLinks** and no joy.
I'm working on mac OSX (SL) and installing in my user's "Sites" directory. I can access any files in this CMS directory via the web browser just not anything through symbolic links.

Comment: Are they absolute or relative symlinks? I'm not sure if that would make a difference, but it might.

Comment: I tried both. It didn't matter which type they were.

Comment: If you added the `FollowSymlinks` directive via `.htaccess`, did you enable `AllowOveride All` for that document root? Otherwise you're not allowed to change it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I eventually solved it. In OSX the final file that governs access of sites installed in user directories is the last *`Include`* line in the `apache2/conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`file. Once I changed that my problems went away.
Thanks to all the people that replied my questions.

Answer (score 6):

I hope *konsolenfreddy*'s comment was helpful already. I am trying to round things up here:

1. First check if the symlinks work from terminal and/or the filesystem in general.
2. Also, if you use absolute paths, the *whole path from root to the file* in question must be readable by the Apache user. *
3. If yes, check if the `AllowOverride` option is set for your webserver (or if applyable for the virtual host) For debugging you can set `AllowOverride All` in either *apache2.conf*, *httpd.conf* or in *sites-available/default*
4. If yes, check if `FollowSymlinks` is aktivated in any of the files responsible for your webroot, starting with apache2 working yourself down to the .htaccess files.
5. Try changing file permissions on the symlink file *and* the target directory (or files)
6. Try creating your own symlink and see what happens when you call it in the browser.

* Check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27050/making-file-in-users-homedir-accessible-from-web-webserver) at askubuntu.com for more hints.

Comment: +1. It might be worth to stress out the passage `the whole path from root to the file in question must be readable`; I was stuck there for awhile.